# Visual Studio 2012 multi-project settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

While including the multiple project where the dll of project 1 is being referred in another ,Is it mandatory to build the sub-project's in release mode and refers its dll in "main" project's reference.

For example if I have this Solution :

```
Solution- Master

   - Project 1
   - Project 2
   - Project 3
   - Project 4
   - Project 5
```

Project 5 is the Main project.While making the Release setup.exe is it mandatory to build each project(1,2,3 and 4) in release mode (selecting the Release from the drop down options) and include the reference of each from /bin/Release of each projects into Project5.

Also where can I set the path of output dll for each project?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not mandatory to have outputs be built to the same underlying configuration - that is, you could define a configuration named "Obscure" and have one project build to release, another to debug and another to staging and whatever.

You can set the output path for projects in the Properties -> Build page (see Output Path).

Comment: Debug setup is always slower than the Release setup. will it not effect the speed of execution if I mesh up the dlls (one from build , one from release and other from staging)

Comment: Now, that's a _different_ question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if a project built in release mode is capable of running independently on the target hardware. Its not really mandatory but good.

Its very easy to set up the output directory for each project, from project properties.

- Right click on the project, select Properties
- For C#, it is one of the Build property page, under Output, Output directory.
- In VB.Net projects, it is on the Compile tab, in the textbox at the top.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

If you add a reference in the Reference Manager, under Solution > Projects, you can browse to .csproj file and it will make the build type equivalent to the build type of the main project.